# How to order items on the same level in Node.js with sequelize-hierarchy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database-design, menu, sequelize.js

How can I order items on the same level?
I want to make a menu based on sequelize-hierarchy.
But there is no "order" option.
The items are ordered by their sequence of insert.

So i have this order:

```
-id:1, hierarchyLevel:1 
-id:2, hierarchyLevel:1
```

But what if I want to get this?:

```
-id:2, hierarchyLevel:1 
-id:1, hierarchyLevel:1
```

Is there a native option for this (the documentation is really poor and I didn't find out anything on Google)? Or do I need to do some shenanigans for this to work after I get the data?

Answer (score 1):

OK, so it looks like it's as easy as define order property of sequelize model... Like so...

```
models.Model.findAll({ 
  ... 
  order: [['id', 'DESC']] 
}) 
.then( res=> { ... })
```

Silly me... Maybe someone will find this useful...